# Combine results of two SQL selects

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following two SQL selects:

```
select 
    u.ID, name, "Desc", sum(pp.amount) as paid
from 
    [dbo].[Users] u, [dbo].[UserTypes] ut, [dbo].[PlayerPayments] pp
where 
    u.UserTypeID = ut.ID 
    and u.ID = pp.UserID
group by 
    u.ID, Name, "Desc";

select 
    u.ID,name, "Desc", sum(ga.GamePrice) as owed, count(ga.ID) as gamesplayed
from 
    [dbo].[Users] u,[dbo].[UserTypes] ut, [dbo].[Games] ga, [dbo].[GamePlayers] gp
where 
    u.UserTypeID = ut.ID 
    and u.ID = gp.UserID 
    and gp.GameID = ga.ID
group by 
    u.ID, Name, "Desc";
```

And they return the following results look like as follows:

[image: Returned result]

How can I combine the results together by adding the two columns (owed and gamesplayed) on the first result set?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a generic solution:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.owed, T2.gamesplayed FROM
(
  select u.ID,name, "Desc", sum(pp.amount) as paid
  from [dbo].[Users] u,[dbo].[UserTypes] ut, [dbo].[PlayerPayments] pp
  where u.UserTypeID = ut.ID and u.ID = pp.UserID
  group by u.ID,Name,"Desc"
) T1
JOIN
(
  select u.ID,name, "Desc", sum(ga.GamePrice) as owed, count(ga.ID) as gamesplayed
  from [dbo].[Users] u,[dbo].[UserTypes] ut, [dbo].[Games] ga, [dbo].[GamePlayers] gp
  where u.UserTypeID = ut.ID and u.ID = gp.UserID and gp.GameID = ga.ID
  group by u.ID,Name,"Desc"
) T2
ON T1.ID=T2.ID
```

Comment: This worked. If I wanted the difference between `paid` and `owed` from the same query, would that be possible?

Comment: You can add column as expression: `T1.paid-T2.owed`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `UNION ALL` or `UNION` (if you want to remove duplicates) and pass default value for extra columns in query 1

```
select u.ID,name, "Desc", sum(pp.amount) as paid, 0 as owed, 0 as gamesplayed
from [dbo].[Users] u,[dbo].[UserTypes] ut, [dbo].[PlayerPayments] pp
where u.UserTypeID = ut.ID and u.ID = pp.UserID
group by u.ID,Name,"Desc";
UNION ALL
select u.ID,name, "Desc", sum(ga.GamePrice) as owed, count(ga.ID) as gamesplayed
from [dbo].[Users] u,[dbo].[UserTypes] ut, [dbo].[Games] ga, [dbo].[GamePlayers] gp
where u.UserTypeID = ut.ID and u.ID = gp.UserID and gp.GameID = ga.ID
group by u.ID,Name,"Desc";
```

**Note** Also the datatypes of extra column added in query 1 must match with columns in query 2 else `UNION` operation will throw error

Comment: Damn! You are quick haha

Comment: Since OP is talking about 'adding columns to the first result set' I think he actually is looking for a JOIN (although I thought he was talking about a union first as well).